# Authentication SQL + AD Users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I need to créate an asp.net mvc application but it should have both kinds of authentication, AD and users from a table, authentication should be done using a form, not Windows integrated.

Is there a provider for this, or do I need to write a custom one? If its custom  how do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Login page that accepts user name and password
As first step in your validation, validate credentials against AD

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, userName, password))
{
     return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
}
```

If this step succeeds, write another call to DB layer to validate the existence of User in your respective Users table; perform Authorization, if needed at the same step.  Some random code

```
// Authenticate the user using Active Directory
if (!AuthenticateUserWithActiveDirectory(userName, password, domain)) return;

// Get user information from database
if (!securityBL.AuthenticateUser(userName)) return;
```

Comment: I can vouch for this answer. This is exactly how I do it to avoid having to store user passwords.